# Древовидный вывод MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, select, parent

| Id | Parent | IndexNumber | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 44161 | NULL | 0 | Задача1 |
| 44162 | 44161 | 0 | Задача1Подзадача1 |
| 44163 | 44161 | 1 | Задача1Подзадача2 |
| 44164 | NULL | 1 | Задача2 |
| 44165 | 44164 | 0 | Задача2Подзадача1 |
| 44166 | 44165 | 0 | Задача2Подзадача1Подподзадача1 |

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4583465) - 11.0.7507.2 (X64)   Nov  1 2020 00:48:37   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

Сейчас запрос, без каких-либо изменений, выводит нужные столбцы. Есть ли способ пронумеровать древовидный вывод.

Ожидаемый результат:

| Num | Id | Parent | IndexNumber | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 44161 | NULL | 0 | Задача1 |
| 1.1 | 44162 | 44161 | 0 | Задача1Подзадача1 |
| 1.2 | 44163 | 44161 | 1 | Задача1Подзадача2 |
| 2 | 44164 | NULL | 1 | Задача2 |
| 2.1 | 44165 | 44164 | 0 | Задача2Подзадача1 |
| 2.1.1 | 44166 | 44165 | 0 | Задача2Подзадача1Подподзадача1 |

Comment: "Задача" и "задача" и "под" меняете на пусто, "Под" меняете на точку. Так устроит?

Comment: Ну или рекурсивный CTE, который преобразует parent-child в FQpath.

Comment: @Kromster, это гениально. Но только данный столбец был так предоставлен для понимания. Или я не правильно Вас понимаю?

Comment: @Akina, вот Вас и ждал тут. Уже используется CTE + 4 JOIN, но с нумерацией проблема. Количество вложенностей не ограничено

Comment: @Akina, в лучшем случае выводить нумерацию хочется. Но подойдёт вариант, если просто будут пробелы вначале вставляться у пункта, для визульной конструкции

Comment: Вы показали условие - вот его решение. Если условие другое - показывайте его )

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS (
    SELECT Id, Parent, IndexNumber, Name, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Parent ORDER BY Id) rn
    FROM test
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT Id, Parent, IndexNumber, Name, rn,
           CAST(rn AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) Num
    FROM cte1
    WHERE Parent IS NULL
  UNION ALL
    SELECT cte1.Id, cte1.Parent, cte1.IndexNumber, cte1.Name, cte1.rn,
           CONCAT(cte2.Num, '.', cte1.rn)
    FROM cte2
    JOIN cte1 ON cte2.Id = cte1.Parent
)
SELECT Num, Id, Parent, IndexNumber, Name
FROM cte2;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0411ec8cc7bfa4afc504d1f522b5b69d